# Finding unmatched study and site in two tables using sql

Tags: sql

I have a scenario where I am trying to follow this logic, Lets say the 'AB' table has 30 studies and 90 sites. Of those 30 studies, 15 studies can be matched with the site table by using study_name only.  Those remaining 15 studies have a total of 30 sites, are all of these 30 sites available in the final view?

final table (is a join view of AB table and another table)

```
study  site
ART    AR-32
ART    AR-33
ART    AR-34
RET    RT-12
```

AB table

```
study site
ART    AR-34
ART    AE-35
RET    RT-12
ART    AR-33
```

site table

```
study  site
ART    AR-33
ART    AR-34
AFT    AR-36
```

Output expected (To check if the study and site which is not matched between AB and site table is available in the final table or not. If it is not there then I need to output those.

```
study site
AFT   AR-36
ART   AE-35
```

Sql code i tried:

```
select 
    coalesce(sps.study, b.study) as study, 
    coalesce(sps.site, b.site) as site
from AB sps
full join site b
on sps.study = b.study and sps.site = b.site
```

I am not sure if this logic is true for my case. Also, i am not sure how to compare this against final table to retrieve those unmatched records. Let give your inputs. Thanks

Comment: This will return everything from both tables, so it seems like it does what you want.

Comment: Yes it does but i am not sure how to check this against the final table through SQL query. I am sure I can do it manually. But its time consuming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select a.study, a.site from
(
select study, site from ab
union 
select study,site from site
)a left join final f on a.study = f.study and a.site = f.site
where f.study is null or f.site is null
```

OR

```
select 
    coalesce(sps.study, b.study) as study, 
    coalesce(sps.site, b.site) as site
from AB sps
full join site b
on sps.study = b.study and sps.site = b.site
left join final f on coalesce(sps.study, b.study) = f.study and coalesce(sps.site, b.site) = f.site
      where f.study is null or f.site is null
```

Comment: for your first query i would like to display only study and site and not all records. Could you pls alter it accordingly?

Comment: Updated it -  u can check now @Ksp

Comment: could you explain the logic? i understand that by doing union btw ab and site we get all study and site. Why a left join with final? doesn't just give all the records from ab and site? How are we trying to get the unmatched records from final here?

Comment: with a left join you'll get all the rows from the left table which is here the result set of union and then applying 'f.study is null or f.site is null' filter you'll get those rows which are not in the final table @KSp, btw, if the answer helped u don't forget to mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: thanks, the only thing I see is that this retrieves all the study and site even the duplicates but I tried distinct and it doesn't work. Could you please guide me?

Comment: @KSp, could you please create your table structure here and also insert some sample data so that I can figure it out - where is the wrong? https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223350/discussion-between-ksp-and-fahmi).